# Custom loss function breaking backpropagation in Pytorch

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, gradient

I am using this class

```
class MonetaryLoss(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,risk,payout):
        super(MonetaryLoss,self).__init__()
        self.risk = risk
        self.payout = payout
    def forward(self,pred,y):
        equity = 100
        pred = t.max(pred,1).indices
        for i in range(len(pred)):
            if (pred[i] == y[i]):
                equity += equity*self.risk*self.payout
            else:
                equity -= equity*self.risk
        print(equity)
        return equity
```

to prepare some examples of custom losses. When I use t.max(pred,1).indices the gradient is lost and this forward() function does not return anything with a gradient. I thought using

```
loss = Variable(t.Tensor[0], requires_grad = True)
```

and then updating the loss variable over training iterations would solve the problem. However, it breaks the backpropagation chain. What is the best way to create this loss and leave the backpropagation chain intact?

Answer (score 0):

You're loss function has to be differentiable in the whole domain, that means no sharp turning points. In layman's terms, has to be "smooth".

Answer (score 0):

What you are taking is the *argmax* of the tensor. Since this operator ***is not*** differentiable. In practical terms, this means you can't backpropagate through that operation *i.e.* call `backward` on the results of `pred.max(1).indices` or similarly `pred.argmax(1)`.

Here have a look:

```
>>> pred = torch.rand(10, 10, requires_grad=True)
>>> values, indices = pred.max(1)

>>> values.grad_fn # can be backpropagated on:
<MaxBackward0 at 0x7febc10d2ed0>

>>> indices.grad_fn # can't be backpropagated on:
None
```